# Mongodb : Find the cities with the highest number of zipcodes and order states by highest zipcode city population

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, database, nosql

The document in collection

```
{ "_id" : "01001", 
"city" : "AGAWAM", 
" loc" : [ -72.622739, 42.070206 ],
"pop" : 15338,
"state" : "MA" }
```

First part is finding cities in each state with highest no. of zipcodes (_id's)

I have this :-

```
db.zips.aggregate([{ 

 $group:
  {
    _id: {state:"$state",city: "$city" }  ,
    count: {$sum:1},
    population:{$sum:"$pop"}
  }
 },
 {
 $sort:{count:-1}
}   
])
```

The output I am getting :-

```
{ "_id" : { "state" : "TX", "city" : "HOUSTON" }, "count" : 93,   "population" : 2095918 }
{ "_id" : { "state" : "CA", "city" : "LOS ANGELES" }, "count" : 56, "population" : 2102295 }
{ "_id" : { "state" : "PA", "city" : "PHILADELPHIA" }, "count" : 48, "population" : 1610956 }
{ "_id" : { "state" : "IL", "city" : "CHICAGO" }, "count" : 47, "population" : 2452177 }
{ "_id" : { "state" : "TX", "city" : "SAN ANTONIO" }, "count" : 45, "population" : 811792 }
{ "_id" : { "state" : "TX", "city" : "DALLAS" }, "count" : 44, "population" : 940191 }
{ "_id" : { "state" : "MO", "city" : "KANSAS CITY" }, "count" : 41,    "population" : 360182 }
```

The problem is I need to find the city with highest no. of zipcode for each state, So each state should be present only once instead of a sorted list. basically I am looking for highest value of zipcode for each state.

Any thoughts on how I can achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add a second $group stage in your aggregation pipeline like this:

```
db.zips.aggregate([
   {
      $group:{
         _id:{
            state:"$state",
            city:"$city"
         },
         count:{
            $sum:1
         },
         population:{
            $sum:"$pop"
         }
      }
   },
   {
      $sort:{
         count:-1
      }
   },
   {
      $group:{
         _id:"$_id.state",
         count:{
            $first:"$count"
         },
         city:{
            $first:"$_id.city"
         },
         population:{
            $first:"$population"
         }
      }
   }
])
```

try it online: [mongoplayground.net/p/_Kpf37svCER](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_Kpf37svCER)

Comment: Thanks ! This really helped my clear a lot of cob webs. Been trying to figure this out for a couple of hours !!